# asymtote and value of a function

Tags: functions

A function is defined as $f(x) =ln(px + q ), x>1$ , it intersects $x$ axis at $(4,0)$ and has asymptote at $x=1$.
We are asked to find value of $p$ and $q$.

By substituting $(4,0)$ in the function I  got one equation $4p+q=1$. I understand we have to form another equation and solve them for $p$ and $q$.

I need help in forming the second equation. I guess as we know we have asymptote at x=1, that should be of some help.

Arif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y = f(x) = Ln(px + q) for x > 1 has an asymptote at x = 1 means that: f(x) --> infinity

when x --> 1. This happens when: p + q = 0 ,and together with 4p + q = 1 we have: p = 1/3,

and q = -1/3. we can check by draw the graph of f(x) = ln(x/3 - 1/3).